# History push not updating new data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

working with a basic reactjs app, after update my form (page name : /update/:id) i want to push to another page called view (page name : /view/:id) unfortunately my new update not reflecting in **/view/:id**,  it's showing old data

Here is my **/update/:id** code

```
  handleSubmit(e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    const data = {
            title: this.state.title
        }
        axios.post('http://localhost:3001/user/bio/update/'+this.props.match.params.id, data)
        .then(res => console.log(res.data));
        this.setState({
            title: ''

        })
        this.props.history.push('/view/' + this.props.match.params.id);
        //this.props.location.state('/view/' + this.props.match.params.id);


    }
```

// router

```
render() {
    return (

       <Router>   
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path='/create' component={ViewId} />
            <Route path="/view/:id" component={ViewId}/>
            <Route path="/bio/update/:id" component={BioUpdateById}/>
          </Switch>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Please share your router config

Comment: updated my question

Comment: Where is your react router implementation?

Comment: updated my question

Comment: And where share the code of ViewId component. Can you make a codesandbox for this?

Comment: Are you browserRouter ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how your app is set, but I would use Redux to store the POST response and use it on the /view/:id component route.

And a GET request on componentDidMount of /view/:id for users who go straight to this route. To avoid a unnecessary request (GET on view) you can check if you have it on Redux before.

But if you want to keep it simple, just add the GET request on view.